# Javascript- How to pass array as parameter at onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that I want to pass to a javascript onclick function. I send that array in the onclick event of a button. The onclick function return me [object Object]. Is there a different way to do call that function with the array?

Here My Code:

```
var data_type= $.parseJSON(data_playtype[1]);//{"1":"apple","2":"orange","23":"berry","8":"grape","9":"mango"}


str1.push('<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="showABC(\''+data_type+'\')">'Data'</td>');



function showABC(fruit){

    $.each(fruit,function(pid,pt){
        alert(pt);
    });

}
```

Comment: Don't use HTML and inline event handlers. Use jQuery to build the DOM elements and to bind the event handler, so you can make use of closures. I highly recommend to read the jQuery tutorial: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/#creating-new-elements, https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: `pt` is an object, so when you do `alert(pt)`, it's stringifying the object to `[object Object]`. Try to access a specific key of that object.

Comment: @JoshBeam: The string conversion already happens earlier when the HTML is built.

Comment: @FelixKling, oh yeah, you're right. Talking about in the string'ed `onClick`, yes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have an array that I want to pass to a javascript onclick function.
>   I send that array in the onclick event of a button. The onclick
>   function return me [object Object]. Is there a different way to do
>   call that function with the array?

Note, `data_type` not appear to be `Array` at `js` ; `data_type` appear to be `Object`

---

Try utilizing `.on()` , calling `showABC()` within `click` event handler with `data_type` as parameter.

```js
var data_playtype = [];

data_playtype[1] = JSON.stringify({
  "1": "apple",
  "2": "orange",
  "23": "berry",
  "8": "grape",
  "9": "mango"
});

var data_type = $.parseJSON(data_playtype[1]);
//{"1":"apple","2":"orange","23":"berry","8":"grape","9":"mango"}

var str1 = [];
str1.push("<td><a href=javascript:void(0)>Data</a></td>");

function showABC(fruit) {

  $.each(fruit, function(pid, pt) {
    alert(pt);
  });

};

$("table tbody").append(str1).find("a")
  .on("click", function() {
    showABC(data_type)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/p5c97h7L/)

Using inline JS is not a good idea. I would use a data attribute to hold the data as follows:

```
var data_type = .....;
var link = $('<a/>').data('data_type', data_type).html('Data');
str1.push( $('<td/>').html( link ) );

//event handler
link.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data_type = $(this).data('data_type');
    .....
});
```

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/data/

> **.data( key, value )**
>
> **key**
>
> Type: String
>   A string naming the piece of data to set.
>
> **value**
>
> Type: Anything
>   **The new data value; this can be any Javascript type except `undefined`.**

Comment: Does jQuery automatically convert objects to JSON when passed to `data`?

Comment: @FelixKling, what exactly do you mean? What's your concern?

Comment: Never mind, I was confused by "data attribute". Forgot that jQuery has its own data store.

Comment: But you do bring up a good point. No actual data attribute is added to the element.